# Gensim Dictionary Implementation

Tags: python, nlp, topic-modeling, gensim

I was just curious about the gensim dictionary implementation. I have the following code:

```
    def build_dictionary(documents):
        dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(documents)
        dictionary.save('/tmp/deerwester.dict') # store the dictionary
        return dictionary
```

and I looked inside the file deerwester.dict and it looks like this:

```
8002 6367 656e 7369 6d2e 636f 7270 6f72
612e 6469 6374 696f 6e61 7279 0a44 6963
7469 6f6e 6172 790a 7101 2981 7102 7d71
0328 5508 6e75 6d5f 646f 6373 7104 4b09
5508 ...
```

the following code, however,

```
my_dict = dictionary.load('/tmp/deerwester.dict') 
print my_dict.token2id #view dictionary
```

yields this:

```
{'minors': 30, 'generation': 22, 'testing': 16, 'iv': 29, 'engineering': 15, 'computer': 2, 'relation': 20, 'human': 3, 'measurement': 18, 'unordered': 25, 'binary': 21, 'abc': 0, 'ordering': 31, 'graph': 26, 'system': 10, 'machine': 6, 'quasi': 32, 'random': 23, 'paths': 28, 'error': 17, 'trees': 24, 'lab': 5, 'applications': 1, 'management': 14, 'user': 12, 'interface': 4, 'intersection': 27, 'response': 8, 'perceived': 19, 'widths': 34, 'well': 33, 'eps': 13, 'survey': 9, 'time': 11, 'opinion': 7}
```

So my question is, since I don't see the actual words inside the .dict file, what are all of the hexadecimal values stored there? Is this some kind of super compressed format? I'm curious because I feel like if it is, I should consider using it from now on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given the example:

```
>>> from gensim import corpora
>>> docs = ["this is a foo bar", "you are a foo"]
>>> texts = [[i for i in doc.lower().split()] for doc in docs]
>>> print texts
[['this', 'is', 'a', 'foo', 'bar'], ['you', 'are', 'a', 'foo']]

>>> dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(texts)
>>> dictionary.save('foobar.txtdic')
```

If you use the `gensim.corpora.dictionary.save_as_text()` (see https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/corpora/dictionary.py), you should have got the below text file:

```
0   a   2
5   are 1
1   bar 1
2   foo 2
3   is  1
4   this    1
6   you 1
```

If you use the default `gensim.corpora.dictionary.save()`, it saves into a pickled binary file. See `class SaveLoad(object)` in https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/utils.py

For information on `pickle`, see http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickle-example